# How to output batch command to null

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, clipboard

```
@echo off
mode con:cols=40 lines=2
echo somestring|clip
cls
echo Wireless Password copied to clipboard.
timeout 2 > NULL
```

How do I make timeout not print any text?

Comment: It is recommended not to publish both your wireless password and your coordinates...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may need to redirect both stdout and stderr:

```
timeout 2  >NUL  2>NUL
```

Note that the special device is `NUL` or `NUL:`, with a single `L`.

Comment: you can also redirect stderr to stdout: timeout > nul 2>&1

Answer (score 1):

Interesting (and annoying) fact for latest Windows 10:
Microsft does not allow piping into nul any longer.

Update: This was a bug in Win10-Insider v18990. It is fixed in v18995.